# Routed AP using OpenWRT

Tags: router, wireless-router, openwrt

### Background

I want to use OpenWRT in to enhance a relatively week signal in one part of the house. The FritzBox router is located far away, and must stay at the top floor. I can't use cables.

### Partial Solution

I am following the [Routed AP Guide](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/routedap) in the OpenWRT wiki, but I can't get my clients from the lan I am setting to ping WWW.
So here is what I have:

1. Fritz!box which I am only allowed to have the WPA key to it. 
    The box issues IP's in the range: `192.168.178.0/255` (ESSID: "FRITZ!Box")
2. My OpenWRT router (with Atheros Chip) with Backfire (10.03.1, r29592).
    My router is giving DHCP with the range: `192.168.1.127`.

### Observations

Before, I followed the guide, I entered the GUI and connected the Router via Wifi->Join to the LAN network of the FRITZ!Box. The client connect to OpenWRT has the address `192.168.1.128`, and can access WWW. From the OpenWrt shell I can also ping WWW.

After Issuing the instructions in the guide, replacing the correct IP addresses where needed. 
I restart everything as said, and I can connect to the new WLAN established with the name `TEST`.
From my single client in that WLAN with the new IP `192.168.178.229` I can now ping the Fritz!Box at `192.168.178.1` and my OpenWRT at `192.168.178.40`.

However, I can't access WWW from client (`192.168.178.229`) or the OpenWRT router.

One, more observation, which might help solving my problem:
I have a bridge defined (by the automatic tools, i didn't add it...).

```
  br-lanroot@OpenWrt:~# ifconfig 
br-lan    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:A5:D8:0E:0D  
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6665 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5088 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:604264 (590.1 KiB)  TX bytes:1095085 (1.0 MiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:A5:D8:0E:0D  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7976 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:91937 frame:0
          TX packets:6272 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:847585 (827.7 KiB)  TX bytes:1656757 (1.5 MiB)
          Interrupt:4 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:A5:D8:0E:0E  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:5 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1102 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1102 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:79550 (77.6 KiB)  TX bytes:79550 (77.6 KiB)

mon.wlan0 Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-24-A5-D8-0E-0D-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11079 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:32 
          RX bytes:2462537 (2.3 MiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:A5:D8:0E:0D  
          inet addr:192.168.178.40  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:927 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:840 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:32 
          RX bytes:115706 (112.9 KiB)  TX bytes:187458 (183.0 KiB)
```

### Extras

```
### ip route default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlan0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.127 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.178.34
```

Can't find `ip route` on the OpenWrt router.

### Question

What prevents my packets from going from my new WLAN "TEST" to the old WLAN "FRITZ!Box" ?

Thanks in advance, 
Oz

Answer (score 0):

Packets reaching the internet router is a good first step so far. 
Maybe the default route is not set up either on the repeater/wifi relay or on the client or on both.
Can you check what "ip route" says on the relay and on the client?

Comment: i added `ip route` output above.